# Let $ f,g : A \rightarrow A (A \subset R)$ be two bijections. Give examples that f+g and fg are not bijections

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Let $ f,g : A  \rightarrow A (A \subset R)$ be two bijections. Give examples that f+g and fg are not bijections.

I am not sure how to approach this question. I try to think of examples, but I can't think of any. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint: Is constant function a bijection? (assuming here by * you mean multiplication)

Comment: I think so? so then like 3 + some function? I'm not sure where you are going with this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Try $A=[-1,1]$, $f(x)=x, g(x)=-x$.

Then $f(x)+g(x) = 0$  is not bijection and $f(x) g(x)=-x^2$ also is not  bijection since $f(1) g(1)=f(-1) g(-1).$

Comment: so this work for f+g right. Thanks! why did you need A=[−1,1]. Also how would a f*g work. would x*1/x work?

Comment: I added some explanaton

Comment: Thanks! so would f+g be not a bijection because it would not be 1 to 1 since everything also equal to zero?

Comment: yes, a constant is not a bijection

Answer (score 1):

Just wish to contribute that in general for these problems it is very convenient to think of graphs on the Cartesian Plane.

*Graphs that do not pass the vertical line test (no two y values for one x value) are not functions.*

and

*Graphs that do not pass the horizontal line test (similarly, no two x values for one y value) are not injective.*

Then it becomes a little easier to think of functions that are not bijective. Consider the graph of x^2. This will not pass the horizontal line test, and therefore any function that maps to it cannot map back (as noted by Leox above).